# Scale height of a div to a pre-determined height on window resize

Tags: jquery, scale, window-resize

I am looking for a solution using Jquery to scale the height of a div when the user re-sizes the browser window and have an ease animation added to it with a slight delay.  I need the `<div>` with the class `.graph` to have a min-height of 300px and be able to grow to 700px on window re-size.

**HTML**

```
<div id="slide1" class="current">

    <div class="graph resize">
    This is where a SVG graph would go
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body,html{
margin:0;
height:100%;
}

.current{
height:100%;
min-height:750px;
position:relative; 
background:#ccc;
padding:5px;
}

.graph{
position:absolute;
width:950px;
min-height:300px;
background:#fafafa;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px #DAD8D8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.  After playing around with jQuery animate and some css properties I have a pretty smooth script working.

I have included a fiddle below if anyone would like to see it work.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanverdel/vtq5W/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).resize(function(){

$('.className').css({
position:'absolute',
left: ($("#slide2, #slide3, #slide4").width() 
 - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
 top: ($(window).height() 
 - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
 });

});

// To initially run the function:

$(window).resize();

$(window).on('load resize', function(){
$('.className').animate({height: $(window).height()-$('.className').height() / 2},300,
function(){

        setInterval(function() {

        $(".className").css({
        top: ($(window).height()
          - $('.className').outerHeight())/2,
        });

        }, 0);
        });
});


});
```